# Confusion between standard finite element and mass-lumping finite element methods

Tags: finite-element, parabolic-pde

Consider the following equation, subject to homogeneous Neumann boundary condition.
$$
u_t = \Delta u + f(u).
$$
The weak formulation is as follows:
$$
(u_t,w) = (\Delta u,  w) + (f(u),w), \quad \forall w \in H^1(\Omega).
$$
The standard finite element scheme is：
$$
(u_{h,t},w_h) = (\Delta_h u_h,  w_h) + (f(u_h),w), \quad \forall w_h \in V^r_h(\Omega),
$$
where the $V^r_h$ denotes the space of polynomials of degree at most r. And the mass lumping method scheme is
$$
(u_{h,t},w_h)_h = (\Delta_h u_h,  w_h)_h + (f(u_h),w)_h, \forall w_h \in V^r_h(\Omega),
$$

or

$$
(u_{h,t},w_h)_h = (\Delta_h u_h,  w_h) + (f(u_h),w)_h, \forall w_h \in V^r_h(\Omega),
$$

where $(\cdot, \cdot)_{h}$ signifies the use of the mass lumping method for integration. The main difference between the above two mass lumping methods is the assembly of the stiffness matrix.

Defined $P_h$：$L^2(\Omega) \to V_h(\Omega)$ denote the $L_2$-projection onto the space of $V_h^r$ , and $\Pi_h: C(\bar{\Omega}) \to V^r_h$ denote the interpolation by a function in $V^r_h$ through the nodes of mass lumping integration nodes. What I want to do is construct the error equation $e_h = u_h - \Pi_h u$, then
$$
\partial_t \Pi_h u(t) - \Delta_h \Pi_h u(t) = \Pi_h f(u) + \underbrace{\Pi_h \Delta u(t) - \Delta_h \Pi_h u (t)}_{g_h(u)}.
$$

$$
\partial_t \Pi_h u(t) - \Delta_h \Pi_h u(t) = \Pi_h f(u) +  \underbrace{P_h \Delta u(t) - \Delta_h \Pi_h u (t)}_{g_h(u)}.
$$

In the paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10915-021-01746-y Lemma 2.4 proof that
$$
(\Pi_h \Delta u - \Delta_h \Pi_h u , w_h) \leq h^{r+1}||u||_{2r+2} ||w_h||_1
$$
Consider the $g_h(u)$ in the second equation:
$$
(g_h(u),w_h) = (P_h \Delta u - \Delta_h \Pi_h u, w_h) = (P_h \Delta u - \Delta u,w_h)  + (\Delta u -  \Delta_h \Pi_h u,w_h).
$$

$$
=(\Delta_h R_h u - \Delta u, w_h) + (\Delta u -  \Delta_h \Pi_h u,w_h)
$$

$$
=(\Delta u -  \Delta_h \Pi_h u,w_h).
$$
where the $R_h$ is the Ritz projection. These two schemes seem to be equivalent, but when I use $(\cdot,\cdot)_h$ to integrate the stiffness matrix, the convergence order will be reduced in some cases. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: How exactly are $\Pi_h$ and $R_h$ defined?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I fixed my problem, now $\Pi_h$ is the Lagrange interpolation operator, which interpolation by a function in $V^r_h$ through the nodes of mass-lumping intergrate nodes. For example, in 1D case, it means interpolate a function through the Gauss-Lobatto nodes. And $P_h$ is a standard L2 projection. $R_h$ is the Ritz projection.